# How to use the Teams SDK authentication with a custom Role Provider

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, microsoft-teams

We have an existing .NET Framework MVC web app that we are adding to a Teams Personal Tab.

We want to be able to authenticate using the Teams SDK (or any Client-side authentication method) and still use our custom User Role Provider.

```
var auser = new UserContextProvider().GetUserContext(Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal);
```

I think (and could be wrong) that we need to get the Client-side authentication to update the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

Comment: Please have look at this sample:-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/csharp
Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Sayali-MSFT, our team reviewed the Microsoft-Teams-Samples last year. I was in the middle of looking into this again, when you replied. This definitely answers this question, but as usual, opens up a ton of other questions. This sample is used for a single tenant and needs modifications to work for multi-tenant situation. It doesn't help that our original application is written in .NET Framework and not Core.

Comment: Here is documentation regarding multi tenant - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps#best-practices-for-multi-tenant-apps
How to convert an app to be multi-tenant-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: Thanks again @Sayali-MSFT. Do you have information on having two types of authentication? Basically, we want to use the Teams SSO in Teams, but use a standard MSAL login when accessing from a browser.

Comment: please have look into this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-sso/csharp
hope it's helpful.
Ref Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication?msclkid=894eb1e7cd2611ecb4d8a4f754766104#web-based-authentication-flow